# Error al cargar nuevo registro en una tabla con clave foránea. Spring Boot + MySQL:"Validation failed for classes during persist time for groups"

Tags: java, mysqli, spring-boot, hibernate, postman

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion web de Portfolio, con SpringBoot y MySQL, tengo una clase `Persona`, una Clase `Usuario`, y una Clase `Localidad`.

La clase `Persona` tiene una clave foránea(`Usuario_id`) con relación `OneToOne` con la clase `usuario`, y una clave foránea(`localidad_id`) con relacion `manyToOne` con la clase `Localidad`. Al querer enviar una solicitud POST con [postman](/questions/tagged/postman) me arroja el siguiente error.

El error simplificado

> "message": "Validation failed for classes [com.proyecto.portfolio.model.Localidad] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]\nList of constraint violations:[\n\tConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='no debe ser nulo', propertyPath=localidad, rootBeanClass=class com.proyecto.portfolio.model.Localidad, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}\n]",

Clase persona:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Persona {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @NotNull
    private String nombre;
    @NotNull
    private String apellido;
    @NotNull
    private String fecha_nacimiento;
    @NotNull
    private String telefono;
    @NotNull
    private String titulo;
    @NotNull
    private String acerca_de;
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id")
     private Usuario usuario;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "localidad_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"id"})
    private Localidad localidad;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "persona", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Educacion> educaciones;
```

Clase Localidad

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Localidad {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @NotNull
    private String localidad;
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "provincia_id")
    private Provincia provincia;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "localidad", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Persona> personas;  
}
```

Clase Usuario

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Usuario {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String nombreUsuario;
    @NotNull
    private String email;
    @NotNull
    private String password;
    @NotNull
    @ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "usuario_rol", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "rol_id"))
    private Set<Rol> roles = new HashSet<>();
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "usuario", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Persona persona;
```

Y este es el JSON que mando con Postman:

```
{
    "acerca_de": "Me gusta la tecnologia",
    "apellido": "Garcia",
    "fecha_nacimiento": "19-03-1987",
    "nombre": "Pablo",
    "telefono": "1168463232",
    "titulo": "Desarrollador Web Full Stack Jr",
    "localidad": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "usuario": {
        "id": 1
    }
}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda!! :)

Comment: intenta ponerle los campos marcados como notnull de usuario y de localidad y nos cuentas si cabia el error.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, ya lo logré solucionar como comenté más abajo!! ¡¡¡Mil gracias!!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final ya lo logré solucionar. El error era que puse

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"id"})
```

pensando que solo tenía efecto al traer la entidad desde la base de datos, pero también lo tiene al querer guardar en la base de datos.

Sacando eso, me arrojo un nuevo error, luego googleé ese error, y decían de cambiar el `casacade.type.All` a `.MERGE`, hice eso y funciono perfectamente.